# Extract columns from file to another file

Tags: python

I got a text file with 17 columns and a few 100s lines. How do I extract only column nr2, 14 and 16 to another file with only those 3 columns with a python script? I want to make a file with 17 columns to a new file with only 3 of those

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, sample input data, any errors and desired output, thanks.

Comment: Ive not tried anything yet, Im new to python and dont know how to do this part

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few sample lines from your text file. How are the columns separated?

Comment: They are separated by a ,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Do you know how to read and write a text file line by line? Do you know how to split a string on a given separator? If not, you should read the documentation: [reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work in standard Python, it makes use of Python's `csv` module to handle the columns automatically:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerows([cols[1], cols[13], cols[15]] for cols in csv_input)
```

Tested using Python 2.7.6. Note lists in Python start from an index of `0`.

For Python 3, use the following:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerows([cols[1], cols[13], cols[15]] for cols in csv_input)
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: Not sure how you got that? Which version of Python are you using? I suggest you copy paste the code and make sure the indenting is correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didnt se that for python 3. Working now, Thx!

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked. When you are finished, you can accept the solution by clicking on the tick to the side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nympy`:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
data = np.array(x for x in csv.reader(open("your_file")))
data[0::, column_number]
            ^^^
          replace column_number with the number you want
```